# Polymer Neon Elements - making the image inside element trigger animation as well

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

### The dev page

http://labs.recgr.com/polymer-dev/our_team.html

### The original Google Polymer demo

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=neon-animated-pages

### The problem

Clicking on (round) image inside the (round) container on *the dev page* doesn't trigger animation.

### My goal

Trigger the _onClick method (as can be seen in source of [this page](http://labs.recgr.com/polymer-dev/circles-page.html)) when visitor clicks on the image itself.

**_onClick method code:**

```
_onClick: function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var target_id = target.getAttribute('data-id');

  if (target.classList.contains('circle')) {
    // configure the page animation
    this.sharedElements = {
      'hero': target
    };

    var nodesToScale = [];
    var circles = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('.circle');
    for (var node, index = 0; node = circles[index]; index++) {
      if (node !== event.target) {
        nodesToScale.push(node);
      }
    }
    this.animationConfig['exit'][1].nodes = nodesToScale;

    this.fire('circle-click', {targetId: target_id});
  }
}
```

### Screenshot of the area in question

[image]

## The question

What's the proper way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: Your link doesn't work... That's why you should almost always include code in your question.

Comment: @JustinXL You're right, but it got garbled because of the SO editor. Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="horizontal layout">
  <div class="circle center-center horizontal layout" data-id="person1"><img src="https://idrycleaningi.com/image/nino/our_team/mich.jpg" data-id="person1" class="circle-image"></div>
  <div class="circle center-center horizontal layout" data-id="person2"><img src="https://idrycleaningi.com/image/nino/our_team/nino.jpg" data-id="person2" class="circle-image"></div>
  <div class="circle center-center horizontal layout" data-id="person3"><img src="https://idrycleaningi.com/image/nino/our_team/snowden.jpg" data-id="person3" class="circle-image"></div>
  <div class="circle center-center horizontal layout" data-id="person4"><img src="https://idrycleaningi.com/image/nino/our_team/bump.jpg" data-id="person4" class="circle-image"></div>
</div>
```

```
_onClick: function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var target_id = target.getAttribute('data-id');

  if (target.classList.contains('circle') || target.classList.contains('circle-image')) {
    // configure the page animation
    this.sharedElements = {
      'hero': target
    };

    var nodesToScale = [];
    var circles = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll('.circle');
    for (var node, index = 0; node = circles[index]; index++) {
      if (node !== event.target) {
        nodesToScale.push(node);
      }
    }
    this.animationConfig['exit'][1].nodes = nodesToScale;

    this.fire('circle-click', {targetId: target_id});
  }
}
```

What I've done is added *circle-image* class to images, and then, instead of just checking for *circle* class (from the Divs), I also permitted *circle-image* class (from images).